# how to install enthoughts python virtualenv (linux mint)

Tags: linux, virtualenv, enthought, canopy, linux-mint

I have a Linux Mint OS (Macbook Air).

The OS already has Python 2.7.6 installed.

However, I want to install Enthoughts/Canopy for all of the Scientific Computing packages (Numpy, Scipy, Pandas etc) and do not want to disturb the system python version.

I want to install enthoughts/canopy in a virtual environment but not sure how to do this.

I have virtualenv installed:

```
virtualenv (13.1.0)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.6)
virtualenvwrapper (4.6.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Your system Python and all its packages will be completely independent of the Canopy Python and all its packages. If you want to use the same package in both Pythons, install it separately in each.

2) Canopy Python (current version) is based on venv, backported from Python 3 to Python 2, so you can't use virtualenv. (The next major release of Canopy (not imminent) will be able to use either or neither virtual environment package, at the user's choice.)

3) Installation instructions for Canopy Python are linked to on the Canopy download page.